# Pandas is.in dataframe subsetting is slow, but only for million+1 rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to filter a pandas dataframe DF for rows who's value in column 'X' are in a particular list.

```
DF_filtered = DF[DF['X'].isin(list.of.interest)]
```

DF is typically millions of rows long.

The following lines of code completes in a fraction of a second:

```
DF_filtered = DF[0:1000000][DF[0:1000000]['X'].isin(list.of.interest)]
DF_filtered = DF[500000:1500000][DF[500000:1500000]['X'].isin(list.of.interest)]
```

This line, however, takes upwards of 15 minutes:

```
DF_filtered = DF[0:1000001][DF[0:1000001]['X'].isin(list.of.interest)]
```

Is this just a weird quirk of pandas/python? I know that it would be simple to wrap this in a batching function, but I really don't know why this is going on.